# How to display labels on pie, doughnut and area charts, in Chart.js versions 4.x.x?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How to display labels on pie, doughnut and area charts, in [Chart.js](https://chartjs.org) versions 4.x.x?

I found many answers on Stack Overflow, about plugin [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo), but it fits to Chart.js versions 2.x.x, and about plugin [chart.js-plugin-labels-dv](https://npmjs.com/package/chart.js-plugin-labels-dv), and about plugin [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples) but these fits to Chart.js versions 3.x.x. None of these plugins are supporte on Chart.js versions 4.x.x.

Comment: V4 Just got released, give it a few days for plugins to adjust

Comment: chartjs-plugin-labels https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels is not compatible with version3 as well. There is a fork where it was updated.